# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. Error?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Money_Donated
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        All_Donations.Show()
        Me.Close()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Derick\Desktop\ICE 9\Donors.accdb"

    End Sub

    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        connString = provider & dataFile
        TextBox1.Clear()
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE (Code = '" & Donators121.Amount_of_money_donatedTextBox.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        myConnection.Close()
        While dr.Read()
            TextBox1.Text = dr("Description").ToString
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should be using the `cmd.Parameters` instead of putting items in the SQL string - that can lead to `SQL Injection Attacks`.

Comment: It looks like you are setting the connection string with an empty string. You need to swap the line `connString = provider & dataFile` with the line `myConnection.ConnectionString = connString`. Otherwise, you are setting the connection string of the connection to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the connection string with an empty string. You need to swap the line `connString = provider & dataFile` with the line `myConnection.ConnectionString = connString`. Otherwise, you are setting the connection string of the connection object to an empty string.

```
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    TextBox1.Clear()
```

Also, as OneFineDay suggests you should use parameters rather than creating SQL strings as your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks but i am still getting the exact same error message?

Comment: If you add a watch on the connString variable can you see what it is set to?

Comment: oh okay   connString value is 'connString' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Try setting the connection string directly. So do: `myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\Derick\Desktop\ICE 9\Donors.accdb"`

Comment: Check what your str string equals at the point of the error. Likely the text box value you are inserting into your SQL is not correct.

Comment: Okay wait maybe I'm doing the wrong thing. So I have made a database in access, I've linked/binded it to a form in visual basic and what I initially want is to add all the input put in the amount of money donated text box which will be viewable as label.text when i run it now how can I do that ?

Comment: So do you have multiple records with the data that you want to put into the textbox or is it a single record you want to display?

Comment: thank you, i found another solution for the problem but again thanks anyway :)